# jQuery UI Dialog: how to retrieve where it was called from

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

First of all I apologize for my english ;-)

I have a `<TABLE>` and each `<TR><TD>` is the pointer to a file. I added a link to call a PHP module that will delete the selected file. I choosed to use the jQUery UI  dialog to confirm deletion but I'm in trouble intercepting the clicked element to pass the HREF value to the `document.location.href` that will call the PHP module.

This is a small part of the HTML (just one line, the HREF value is different for each `<TR>`):

```
    <tr class="riga">
        <td>
           <?php echo $xName; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="TD20">
           <span class="file-remove">
              <a href=<?php echo "del.php?&op=delfile&i=$xId&f=$xFsname"; ?> >
                 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Delete file"></span>
              </a>
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
...

<div id="confirm-delete-file" title="Conferma rimozione FILE">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Confermi la rimozione definitiva del file?</p>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery function

```
$(function() {
    $( "#confirm-delete-file" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen:false,
      buttons: {
        "Elimina": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location.href = document.activeElement.href;
        },
        "Annulla": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    $(".file-remove a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirm-delete-file').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Using Mozilla Firefox it works but it doesn't if using Chrome or Safari. I guess that document.activeElement.href is not the right way to retrieve the href attribute of the clicked ...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S. jQuery UI 1.10.2 and jQuery 1.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then, the problem is in accessing `href` of clicked anchor tag. If so then, declare one global var that can hold `href` of clicked `a` tag and then use it inside **Elimina** function.

```
  var urlToHit = ""; 
  $( "#confirm-delete-file" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen:false,
      buttons: {
        "Elimina": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           alert(urlToHit);
           window.location.href = urlToHit;
        },
        "Annulla": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    $(".file-remove a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        urlToHit = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#confirm-delete-file').dialog('open');
    });
```

Here `urlToHit` will be accessible inside your function and you can redirect to that location w/o any problem.

Comment: PERFECT!! It works with IE, FF... I'll try Chrome later but I'm shure it will be ok! Thanks a lot!!